# What I'm doing wrong by implementing chain rule from scratch?

Tags: python, math, derivative

I'm trying to implement [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) in plain Python. Here is the code from my colab:

```
def calc_derivative(func, x, dx):
  return (func(x + dx) - func(x)) / dx
```

```
def chain_diff(func1, func2, x, dx):
  return calc_derivative(func1(func2), x, dx) * calc_derivative(func2, x, dx)
```

```
def func1(f):
  g = np.log
  def apply(x):
    return g(f(x))
  return apply

def func2(x):
  return x ** 4
```

```
span = 100

y, dy = [], []
tst = []
for x in range(1, span):
  x *= .1
  dx = np.sqrt(2e-15) * x
  dy.append(chain_diff(func1, func2, x, dx))
  y.append(func1(func2)(x))
  tst.append(4 / x)

plt.plot(dy)
plt.plot(tst)
plt.plot(y)
plt.ylim((-10, 10))
plt.legend(("$dy$", "tst plot","y"))
plt.show()
```

*tst* - baseline derivative

*dy* - calculated derivative

For this setup I obtain the following plot:

[image: Plot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `f'(g(x))` vs. `calc_derivative(func1(func2), x, dx)`, I think what you're supposed to be doing is taking a derivative of f around the point g(x). So something like `calc_derivative(func1, func2(x), dx)`? Guessing, haven't tried it (see also: [mre]).

Comment: On a sidenote, we tend to get much more accurate results by writing the symmetric formula `def calc_derivative(func, x, dx): return (func(x + dx) - func(x - dx)) / (2 * dx)` instead of `def calc_derivative(func, x, dx): return (func(x + dx) - func(x)) / dx`. Mathematically, they both converge to the same number when dx tends towards 0, if the function is differentiable at x; but with a fixed, small value of dx, the symmetric formula is usually better.

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest defining a function `compose`, as `def compose(f, g): def fog(x): return f(g(x)); return fog`, and then using `compose` to write things like `compose(func1, func2)` instead of `func1(func2)`, because writing `func1(func2)` forces you to use this unpractical definition of `func1` where `func1` is not really the function you want (`np.log` in your example) but a function which must be applied to another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @teapot418 I've found an issue. I should add *dx* to the argument of the outer function (func1) instead of adding it to the inner one (func2). That  is why my code become the following:

```
def chain_diff(func1, func2, x, dx):
  return calc_derivative(func1(func2), x, dx) * calc_derivative(func2, x, dx)
```

```
def func1(f):
  g = np.log
  def apply(x, dx):
    return g(f(x, 0) + dx)
  return apply

def func2(x, dx):
  return (x + dx) ** 4
```

```
def calc_derivative(func, x, dx):
  return (func(x, dx) - func(x, 0)) / dx
```

```
span = 100

y, dy = [], []
tst = []
for x in range(1, span):
  x *= .1
  dx = np.sqrt(2e-15) * x
  dy.append(chain_diff(func1, func2, x, dx))
  y.append(func1(func2)(x, 0))
  tst.append(4 / x)

plt.plot(dy)
plt.plot(tst)
plt.plot(y)
plt.ylim((-10, 10))
plt.legend(("$dy$", "tst plot","y"))
plt.show()
```

Now I understand calculus slightly better. Thanks!